# asp.net login control - remember me

Tags: asp.net, webforms

When the user uses the "remember Me" option in the login control, it obviously stores a cookie somewhere and the log in gets automated.

Unfortunately I use the login controls "Logged In" event to set up other objects. When the user goes in with the Remember Me function they can bypass this event.

Is there another event i cat catch?

Failing that, is there a safe way to query the membership system to see who is logged in at any time? then i can test myself.

Thanks

Comment: you can use User.Identity.Name to know the loggedin user name

Comment: thanksworks nicely, would llove to know if there is an event i can hook into tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with `User.Identity.Name`

```
if (Request.Cookies["myCookie"] != null)
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("myCookie");
            String UserName = cookie.Values["username"];
            this.Login1.RememberMeSet = !(String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create an `HTTP Handler` or use `Application Events` to check if user is authenticated and set up other objects

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can find any other membership event after LoggedIn , however you can get events from Page Life Cycle.

I suppose you must be redirecting to some default page after successful log in. You can try following code to get the loggedin user name if login was success.

```
User.Identity.Name
```